# minimum distance between two set of 2D points (x1,y1) , (x2,y2)

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have a problem as described in the title and I am using MATLAB 2020.

I have 2 sets of 2D points, and I want to find the two points (each point from a different set)
that has the minimal distance from all the other points `min(distance(pi,pj))`
I done some research (google) and found this article:
"Optimal Algorithms for Computing the Minimum Distance Between Two Finite Planar Sets"
in this web page:

[What is the fastest algorithm to calculate the minimum distance between two sets of points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700983/what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-to-calculate-the-minimum-distance-between-two-sets)

I tried to implement the algorithm, using MATLAB, and a code for Garbriel graph (which I found in google)
here:

http://matgeom.sourceforge.net/doc/api/matGeom/graphs/gabrielGraph.html

the problem is that when I run the code,which suppose to be the algorithm vs a "brute force algorithm" (two loops) , the brute force is always faster... no matter how many points I used , and it is way faster... which is in contrast to logic (mine) and the article mention above.

when I check the execution time of the code lines, I found that the line

```
dist = dist + (repmat(p1(:,i), [1 n2])-repmat(p2(:,i)', [n1 1])).^2;
```

in :

```
minDistancePoints(p1, varargin)
```

is the "problem"
and advises?
thank you

p.s
let

```
set1=random(100,2) 
set2=random(100,2)
```

i want to find the point1 in set1 and the point2 in set2 that have minimum distance from all the other points.

Comment: Can you share an example? Bruteforce will be faster if each of your set of 2D points have 1 point. Likely the alternative will be faster if you have 1 million points. Maybe the implementations of each of the methods are suboptimal. We can't know without a complete example

Comment: That Gabriel graph routine (1) seems to itself compute all pairs distances (2) calls `delaunayn`. You should just build on top of `delaunayn` directly.

Comment: Have you tried [dsearchn](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dsearchn.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Using implicit expansion, we can compute all the possible combination at once and then find point in `p1` that minimize the sum of the distance:

```
p1 =    [0 -1;
         2 3;
         8 8]
p2 =    [1 1;
         2 3;
         3 5;
         3 3]
         
[~,closest_p1] = min(sum(sum((permute(p1,[3,2,1])-p2).^2,2).^0.5))
```

I add a dimension to `p1` with: `permute(p1,[3,2,1])`, so now we can compute all the combination in this new third dimension.

`closest_p1` give the index of the point that minimize the sum of the euclidian distance between each points in `p2`. In this example `closest_p1 = 2`.

Noticed also that the algorithm that you use seems to also compute all the possible combination.

Comment: i forgot to mention that, since my code suppose to run several  times with a large amount  of points (data) , i want the code to be efficient as possible, from what i read the most efficient is of O(nlog n)